# Can't use SSD as datadir for geth on a PI 4 running ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi4, go-ethereum, geth

I'm trying to set up a Medalla test net validator on a Raspberry Pi 4 using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@SomerEsat/guide-to-staking-on-ethereum-2-0-ubuntu-medalla-teku-170e2c52bd23), with the difference that I've pulled the [ARM64 Ethereum package from here.](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/)

I'm running Ubuntu v20.04 (LTS) x64

I managed to sync the testnet this morning, but only by using /var/library/goethereum as my
--datadir. Obviously, that's not going to work long term given the recommended 500GB storage for the eventual size of the blockchain.

I have a Samsung T5 SSD mounted into a blue USB (i.e. USB 3.0) of the Pi.

When I try writing to my ssd using --datadir /mnt/t5/goethereum/

Two behaviours are different. The log reports:

> Aug 16 13:37:21 ethnode-f4f1e111d geth[7435]: Fatal: Error starting
> protocol stack: listen unix /mnt/t5/goethereum/geth.ipc: bind:
> input/output error Aug 16 13:37:21 ethnode-f4f1e111d systemd[1](https://medium.com/@SomerEsat/guide-to-staking-on-ethereum-2-0-ubuntu-medalla-teku-170e2c52bd23):
> geth.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Aug
> 16 13:37:21 ethnode-f4f1e111d systemd[1](https://medium.com/@SomerEsat/guide-to-staking-on-ethereum-2-0-ubuntu-medalla-teku-170e2c52bd23): geth.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'.

And when I attempt to attach geth using

```
geth attach ipc:/mnt/t5/goethereum/geth.ipc
```

I get

> Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix
> /mnt/t5/goethereum/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused

I'm running geth as user goeth, and mounted the T5 as owned by that user.

Contents of /etc/systemd/system/geth.service

```
[Unit]
   Description=Ethereum go client
   After=network.target 
   Wants=network.target
[Service]
   User=goeth 
   Group=goeth
   Type=simple
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=5
   ExecStart=geth --goerli --http --datadir /mnt/t5/goethereum/
[Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
```

Permissions in /mnt/t5 are:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 goeth goeth 131072 Aug 16 13:48 geth
-rwxrwxrwx 1 goeth goeth      0 Aug 16 13:48 geth.ipc 
drwxrwxrwx 1 goeth goeth 131072 Aug 16 13:46 keystore
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[As Karslabe mentioned in this comment](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16215#issuecomment-369192502), you can't host your geth.ipc file on a non-unix volume. But fortunately you can specify different directories for your data and your geth.ipc file.

The answer was to edit my /etc/systemd/system/geth.service thus:

```
[Unit]
   Description=Ethereum go client
   After=network.target
   Wants=network.target
[Service]
   User=goeth
   Group=goeth
   Type=simple
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=5
   ExecStart=geth --goerli --http **--ipcpath  /var/lib/goethereum/geth.ipc**   --datadir /mnt/t5/goethereum/
[Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
```